# Andengine How make a children behind the parent

Tags: android, andengine

i a fee

```
fee = new AnimatedSprite(0, 463, this.mFairyTextureRegion);
```

I would like a children follow fee i use this code but particleSystem is always before

```
    mScene.attachChild(fee);
//mScene.getLastChild().attachChild(particleSystem);    
fee.attachChild(particleSystem);
fee.setZIndex(fee.getZIndex()+1);
particleSystem.setZIndex(particleSystem.getZIndex()-1);
//fee.sortChildren();
mScene.sortChildren();
```

How make a children behind the parent fee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage this by altering andengine itself as described here,

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/drawing-children-behind-it-parent-not-possible-with-zindex-t4810.html

I change the order in the class,

\AndEngine\src\org\anddev\andengine\entity\IEntity.java

```
protected void onManagedDraw(final GL10 pGL, final Camera pCamera) {
    pGL.glPushMatrix();
    {
        this.onApplyTransformations(pGL);
        //Saw these next two araound
        this.onDrawChildren(pGL, pCamera); //Draw children first
        this.doDraw(pGL, pCamera); //Then the parent


    }
    pGL.glPopMatrix();
```

}

It might be an idea to add a public flag to this class so you can toggle child to be drawn in front/behind its parent. Note that this is for GLES 1, I don't know if a better solution was introduced in GLES2.